# Issue in understanding 'This' keyword

Tags: javascript

Why does in the following code, i don't see output as `T12345 ABC` and instead i see `undefined undefined.`

The reason i am expecting `T12345 ABC` because myCarDetails  now refer to global context and `global context have registrationNumber  and brand defined`.

```
var registrationNumber = "T12345";
var brand =  "ABC";

var car = { 
    registrationNumber: "T12345",
    brand: "ABC",

    displayDetails: function(){
        console.log(this.registrationNumber + " " + this.brand);
    }
}

var myCarDetails =  car.displayDetails;
myCarDetails();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: May i know why this is duplicate, The question you referred is an overview of this operator whereas i am talking about specific problem under 'this' umbrella !

Comment: What execution environment are you using? Your code works exactly as you expect it to work in Firefox via the console.

Comment: @Pointy i am using developer.mozilla.org

Comment: huh?  No I mean how are you running the code?

Comment: While `this` refers to the global object, `var registrationNumber` and `var brand` may not be defined in global scope. It really depends on how the whole piece of code is executed.

Comment: On Mozilla, there is live javascript code run option. right? i am using that

Comment: @simbada you are asking about scope of 'this', which is a very common and often duplicated question on SO that has been answered countless times.

Comment: There are likely not evaluating the code in global scope. If you want to ensure that `registrationNumber` and `brand` are defined in global scope, do `window.registrationNumber = ...;` instead.

Comment: Ah well it must be the case that what appears to be the global (`window`) scope is actually *not* the global scope in that environment.

Comment: Hi, Just it should work fine, I tested in chrome

Comment: @pointy great i see your point and now getting close to find the reason, By the way if it has been global scope window then the output should be what i am expecting. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly — if you copy the exact code you posted and paste it into your browser developer console, it should work (it did for me in Firefox)

Comment: You can do a simple test: `var simbada1 = "Hello World!"; console.log(window.simbada1);` If that says `undefined` then the outer scope of the execution environment is not really the global scope.

Comment: @Pointy great. all clear.

Answer (score 0):

When we try to access any property of an Object which is a function itself, in this case way to access this property is -

var myCarDetails = car.displayDetails();

myCarDetails

Complete Working code is as Follows -->

var car = {
        registrationNumber: "T12345",

```
         brand: "ABC",

         displayDetails:  function() {

         console.log(this.registrationNumber + " " + this.brand);
         }
       }
```

var myCarDetails = car.displayDetails();

myCarDetails;

Additional Resource --> https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_objects.asp